# How to get a height of the full data from MasterData (FastReport template)?

Tags: pascalscript, fastreport

I wanna get a Height of MasterData whith full generated data. Normally i use on event `onAfterCalcHeight` of MasterData

```
 if engine.FreeSpace <= GroupHeader2.Height  + MasterData1.Height  then
engine.NewPage;
```

.I need Above line of code, because my template cut of Data beetwen pages.

Comment: Use two pass report. Store height of the first MasterData for each group in the report's variable on the first pass, use this value in the group header OnBeforePrint on the second pass

Comment: It works, but the template creates a very long time. 
Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was the order of events.

First i create a global double variables, for full masterdata1.Height and another height-variable components.

```
var  
masterdata_Height,GroupHeader2_Height: double;
```

Next on masterdata event `OnAfterCalcHeight` a simple

```
  masterdata_Height:=masterdata.Height;
```

Same whith another FastReport headers.

After this on All Headers Event `OnBeforePrint` I add a condition :

```
if engine.FreeSpace <= (masterdata_Height + GroupHeader2_Height)  then
engine.NewPage;
```

In parentheses condition adds all sizes headers approaching the headline event.